# Bash output misunderstanding

Tags: python, nlp

I apologize if this is a duplicate, I couldn't find any other examples of this question.

I'm trying to write a program for natural language recognition, and I was reading a blog post where someone had attempted to do something similar and it recommended using these two lines to capture the output.

```
#capture output of script
./get-language.py | tee preptxt
```

I can't figure out what this code is attempting to do. I assume it's running the get-language file, but that syntax doesn't look correct to me. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Have you tried running it? It doesn't look right to be either - does it work?

Comment: That's a shell command, not Python.

Comment: its not python, its a shell script

Answer (score 5):

On Unix systems you can run executable files with `/path/to/my/executable`.
This is nothing python specific. 
As `.` is the current working directory, you are executing the `get-language.py` script located in the current directory.

However, there are two things you need to do, to get this working for your scripts:

### 1. add a shebang

This is the first line of your script, it tells the shell which program to use.
To use the python interpreter that is first in the `PATH` use:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

### 2. Add the permissions to make your script executable:

You need to permit execution of your script. This can be done with `chmod`:

```
chmod +x myscript.py
```

The last part is a so called piping operation.
If you call two programs like this:

```
$ program_a | program_b
```

The output (stdout) of `program_a` is fed into `program_b`.

Answer (score 2):

That's a shell thing, not Python. `.` is the current directory; you're running `get-language.py` from there.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a line of python, but rather a shell script.

It is running a script called get-language.py (which I assume was described elsewhere on that blog and does the actual language processing), and then it is "piping" that output through the unix command line program [tee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_%28command%29), which stores the output in a file.

Piping takes the output of one program, and uses it as the input of another program.

Comment: I see.  Thanks for the explanation!